# Adding new values to objects

Tags: javascript, html, object, addition

I have an array object and would like it so I can add additional username and passwords of different users. If the username or password does not exist, it'll create it automatically. I thought my array object would work like this: userInfo[0]["username"] is user1, userInfo[1]["username"] is user2, etc.
Here is the jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xkxn54bx/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <title>Generation X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="username"><br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="pass-word" id="password">
    <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Access">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var userInfo = [
    { username: "admin", password: "test" }
];

function addUser(username, password) {
    userInfo[userInfo.length + 1]["username"] = username;
    userInfo[userInfo.length + 1]["password"] = password;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function() {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        for (i = 0; i < userInfo.length; i++) {
            if (username == '' || password == '') {
                alert("All fields are required!");
            }
            else if (username == userInfo[i]["username"]) {
                if (password == userInfo[i]["password"]) {
                    alert("Welcome");
                }
                else {
                    alert("You have entered an invalid password!");
                }
            }
            else {
                addUser(username, password);
                alert("Account created!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are accessing the array correctly, when adding new objects to it. It should be as:

```
function addUser(username, password) {
    userInfo[userInfo.length - 1]["username"] = username;
    userInfo[userInfo.length - 1]["password"] = password;
}
```

Since length is always one more than the last index and that's the index that you want to populate with the new object. If you instead use:

userInfo[userInfo.length + 1]["username"] = username;

Then you are skipping one index.
Also, it is a good idea to create an object at that index first:

```
function addUser(username, password) {
    userInfo[userInfo.length]={};

    userInfo[userInfo.length - 1]["username"] = username;
    userInfo[userInfo.length - 1]["password"] = password;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this message: TypeError: userInfo[userInfo.length] is undefined

Comment: can you see any value for userInfo in the console? how about userInfo.length?

Comment: I defined the length in a variable like so: var userLength = userInfo.length;

Comment: Thanks, Sean. +1. I have another question; in my code, once I create the new user by clicking the "Access" button the browser reloads and empties the object. Any way to save it, or is that where node js or php comes in?

Comment: actually, ...looking at the code, now that you have populated the index with the new object, you need to add properties to it: as `userInfo[userinfo.length -1]["username"] = username; `  , same goes for adding password

Comment: you can save the value(s) in a cookie or local storage or session storage....but all of that is for the client side. To keep it on the server, you need to use a database, unless you want to only use it in the server cache, which will be preserved only as long as the server is running.